# ModelChoiceField gives "Select a valid choice" error on submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here is my simple form with one `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class PropertyFilter(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Property.objects.order_by().values_list('type', flat=True).distinct(),
                                  empty_label=None)
```

It allows user to choose from one of the options (each represented as a string). When i choose an option and hit "Submit" - it returns:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

My `views.py` looks like this:

```
from models import Property
from .forms import PropertyFilter

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PropertyFilter(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PropertyFilter()
        properties = Property.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',  context=locals())
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The queryset parameter for `ModelChoiceField` cannot be `values_list`, because it's going to save the relationships, so django have to use complete model objects, not certain values of model objects.

If you want to show custom choice text, you should define a simple choice field yourself, in django way. You can subclass the django form `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance` method to return what text you want to show:

```
class PropertyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.type

class PropertyFilter(forms.Form):
    type = PropertyModelChoiceField(queryset=Property.objects.all())
```

Something not related, but it's better to use `PropertyFilterForm` as form name, it will make your code clearer to read. Also `type` is a reserved word in python, so try to use something else for your field name like `property_type` would be better.

**Edit:**

I think you(and I as well) are confused of what's your original intention. You need to choose `types` of `Property` from selection, not `Property` objects, so you need to use `ChoiceField` instead:

```
class PropertyFilter(forms.Form):
    type_choices = [(i['type'], i['type']) for i in Property.objects.values('type').distinct()]
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=type_choices)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain how the code you provided will fit with the one i already have?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, but I've already provided the whole thing. You first subclass the django default `forms.ModelChoieField` to create a custom field, then your form `PropertyFilter` uses the new field we created.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand :) Is there any way to choose distinct type values?

Comment: Hm. Property.objects.distinct() - returns duplicates. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you confused your self on how to define `PropertyFilter`. Sounds like you can't use `ModelChoiceField` for your field, but `ChoiceField`, because you are not selecting `Property` model objects, you are just selecting `types`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks :) And what use cases would require using ModelChoiseField?

Comment: I updated my answer. Look at django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield, it doesn't have a specific situation to use `ModelChoiceField`, but mostly  assigning a object as `ForeignKey` to another model.  Also from other sources: http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/forms/fields.html#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: Thanks!!!! Could you please show the correct way of selecting distinct values only?? Because there are still duplicates :(

Comment: Keep getting this error:  type_choices = [(obj.type, obj.type) for obj in Property.objects.values('type').distinct()]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: I've tried running the same thing in the console, and here is what i got: >>> Property.objects.values('type')
[{'type': u'House'}, {'type': u'adsfadf'}, {'type': u'asdf'}, {'type': u'asdf'}, {'type': u'House'}]
>>> Property.objects.values('type').distinct()
[{'type': u'House'}, {'type': u'adsfadf'}, {'type': u'asdf'}, {'type': u'asdf'}, {'type': u'House'}]

Comment: No you didn't read my code carefully, I put `i['type']` not `obj.type`. Each item is an individual dictionary(or hashtable or whatever name you are familiar with).